# How to pass *dynamic* props in React.createElement method?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

A component receives a different component in JSON. I parse it to a React element with **React.createElement** method, I'm passing an "active" boolean field in **props** and it's being saved as a "generalFilter" object in the "plugins" array:

```
generalFilter: React.createElement(childComponent, {
      active: activePlugins.includes(hit)
    })
```

Then I map the "plugins" array and render all the "generalFilter" objects like this:

```
{plugins.map((plugin) => (
    <div>{plugin.generalFilter}</div>
))}
```

But the props in React.createElement **don't seem to be dynamic**, so changing the state of an "active" field isn't detected by a child component.
I thought the above way is the equivalent of:

```
<GeneralFilter active={activePlugins.includes("example")} />
```

where props **are dynamic**. 
**Is there a way to have dynamic props in React element rendered from JSON?**
If not, then I thought about adding props in HTML tag instead of in React.createElement, like this:

```
{plugins.map((plugin) => {
    const GeneralFilter = plugin.components.generalFilter;
    return (
        <GeneralFilter active={activePlugins.includes("example")} />
    )
})}
```

but it throws:

> TS2604: JSX element type 'GeneralFilter' does not have any construct or call signatures.